# PySpark Can't substring into variable

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I'm trying to get the value from a column to feed it later as a parameter. I need to substring it to get the correct values as the date format is DDMMYYYY.

[image: Spark notebook sample]

But when I try applying the substring into the resulting variable, a Column object type is generated.. any suggestions?

Comment: Alternatively can you do a substring in sql query itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't call Spark functions on Python strings. You need to use Python string methods, e.g.

```
print(dataCollect[:3])
```

which should give '301'.